# Issue with getting the rank of a user based on combined columns in a join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, dense-rank

I have a `users` table and each user has flights in a `flights` table. Each flight has a departure and an arrival airport relationship within an `airports` table. What I need to do is count up the unique airports across both departure and arrival columns (`flights.departure_airport_id` and `flights.arrival_airport_id`) for each user, and then assign them a rank via `dense_rank` and then retrieve the rank for a given user id.

Basically, I need to order all users according to how many unique airports they have flown to or from and then get the rank for a certain user.

Here's what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT u.rank FROM (
    SELECT 
        users.id,
        dense_rank () OVER (ORDER BY count(DISTINCT (flights.departure_airport_id, flights.arrival_airport_id)) DESC) AS rank
    FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN flights ON users.id = flights.user_id
    GROUP BY users.id
) AS u WHERE u.id = 'uuid';
```

This works, but does not actually return the desired result as `count(DISTINCT (flights.departure_airport_id, flights.arrival_airport_id))` counts the combined airport ids and not each unique airport id separately. That's how I understand it works, anyway...  I'm guessing that I somehow need to use a `UNION` join on the airport id columns but can't figure out how to do that.

I'm on Postgres 13.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a lateral join to unpivot, then aggregation and ranking:

```
select *
from (
    select f.user_id, 
        dense_rank() over(order by count(distinct a.airport_id) desc) rn
    from flights f 
    cross join lateral (values 
        (f.departure_airport_id), (f.arrival_airport_id)
    ) a(airport_id)
    group by f.user_id
) t
where user_id = 'uuid'
```

You don't really need the `users` table for what you want, unless you do want to allow users without any flight (they would all have the same, highest rank). If so:

```
select *
from (
    select u.id, 
        dense_rank() over(order by count(distinct a.airport_id) desc) rn
    from users u
    left join flights f on f.user_id = u.id
    left join lateral (values 
        (f.departure_airport_id), (f.arrival_airport_id)
    ) a(airport_id) on true
    group by u.id
) t
where id = 'uuid'
```

Comment: Cheers! I do need to allow users without flights. I had to swap `f.user_id` for `u.id` in your second example for it to work. The lateral join is a bit over my head, will need to read up on it!

Answer (score 1):

You're counting the distinct pairs of (departure_airport_id, arrival_airpot_id). As you suggested, you could use `union` to get a single column of airport IDs (regardless of whether they are departure or arrival airports), and then apply a count on them:

```sql
SELECT user_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS user_rank
FROM   (SELECT   u.id AS user_id, COALESCE(cnt, 0) AS cnt
        FROM     users u
        LEFT JOIN     (SELECT user_id, COUNT DISTINCT(airport_id) AS cnt
                       FROM   (SELECT user_id, departure_airport_id AS airport_id
                               FROM   flights
                               UNION
                               SELECT user_id, arrival_airport_id AS airport_id
                               FROM   flights) x
                       GROUP BY u.id) f ON u.id = f.user_id) t
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but doesn't give me ranks for users without flights.

Comment: @shabushabu you can add another level to the query, move the `group by` there and then left join on it - see my edited answer